# Codeigniter access input type inside echoed table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table echoed inside from controller and loaded into a div id via jquery trigger event. The problem is that the table consists of input type texts that I made to datepickers but it's not working. Here is my code inside the controller:

```
echo "<table class='table table-striped table-borderless' width='100%'>
               <tbody>
                <tr>
                 <td><label class='control-label'>AWOL</label></td>
                  <td><select class='form-control' id='cmbawol1' name='cmbawol1'>";
                   $awol_code = array();
                   $awol_code[] = $val['AWOL'];
                   echo "<option value='".$val['AWOL']."'>".$val['AWOL']."</option>";
                   foreach($data['offense'] as $value)
                   {
                    if(!in_array($value['Offense'],$awol_code))
                    {
                        echo "<option value='".$value['Offense']."'>".$value['Offense']."</option>";
                    }
                   }
                   echo "</select></td>
                    <td><input type='text' class='form-control' id='txtawol1' name='txtawol1' value='".$date1."'/></td>
                     </tr>
```

and this is the jQuery that I always use to create datepicker:

```
$('#txtawol1').datepicker();
```

For other pages it works because they are not echoed inside the controller. Please note that this table is inside my edit function meaning it have a default value from my database.

I have the table structure with button on  on the last column and I access it via this code:

```
$(document).on('click','#btnviolation',function(){
   ............code goes here
});
```

But I don't know how for input types.

Comment: I can make the input type to date but ti will not accept formatting not like the datepicker....

Comment: I have a button echoed also from inside the controller but I can access it bu using this code $(document).on('click','#btnviolation',function(){ but I don't know how to use it for input type text....

Comment: Does my question is hard to understand or there is no possible answer to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solved y own problem and this is my solution:

```
$(document).on('focus','#txtawol1',function(){
$(this).datepicker();
});
```

I hope that others may find my code helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the datepicker is not working because the code is loaded **after** the DOM is rendered in the browser.

You can put all the table code in the view and pass the needed values from the controller to the view like this:

```
$data = array(
    'AWOL' => $val['AWOL'], // array
    'Offense' => $value['Offense'] // array
);

$this->load->view('edit_view', $data);
```

And then get the data values in the view like so:

```
<?php foreach ($Offense as $item): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $item; ?>"><?php echo $item; ?></option>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: my edit function is loaded inside a modal so the only way to pass the value and table are via echo from controller.....